# Single node hadoop setup Ubuntu 10.04

Tags: java, ubuntu, hadoop

I am following this tutorial http://www.michael-noll.com/tutorials/running-hadoop-on-ubuntu-linux-single-node-cluster/

I am getting this error when trying to format the hdfs file system

```
/usr/local/hadoop/bin/hadoop: line 320: /usr/lib/jvm/jav-6-sun/bin/java: No such file or directory
/usr/local/hadoop/bin/hadoop: line 390: /usr/lib/jvm/jav-6-sun/bin/java: No such file or directory
/usr/local/hadoop/bin/hadoop: line 390: exec: /usr/lib/jvm/jav-6-sun/bin/java: cannot execute: No such file or directory
```

When I echo java home this is what i get

```
mco@mco-desktop:~$ echo $JAVA_HOME
/usr/lib/jvm/java-6-sun
```

This is my java path in hadoop-env.sh

```
# The java implementation to use.  Required.
export JAVA_HOME=/usr/lib/jvm/jav-6-sun
```

running Ubuntu 10.04 and hadoop 1.0.4

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This is simply a typo, you didn't write `java` correctly in your **hadoop-env.sh** file. It should read like this:

```
# The java implementation to use.  Required.
export JAVA_HOME=/usr/lib/jvm/java-6-sun
```

And not:

```
# The java implementation to use.  Required.
export JAVA_HOME=/usr/lib/jvm/jav-6-sun
```

Don't forget to restart your cluster afterwards to take this into consideration.